# React Proptypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

React provides proptypes for type checking as the following code block demonstrates:

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
    );
  }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};
```

But I can do the following as well for the 'name' proptype:

```js
Greeting.propTypes = {
      name: String
    };
```

In the later case i don't need to include the 'prop-types' module. Which one is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 1):

The first way is the recommended way.

When you do

```
Greeting.propTypes = {
      name: String
    };
```

you are defining a javascript string field inside your proptypes object. Also, you will not be able to make the prop a required prop by using the above.

By using this

```
Greeting.propTypes = {
          name: Proptypes.string.isRequired
        };
```

you can make the proptype required and show a console warning if it is not supplied.